# What is the Sitecore Community Mentor Program and how can I join?

Tags: community, mvp

I just heard about the Sitecore Community Mentor Program, but what it is really and how can I join?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Sitecore would like to support all of those who would like to contribute to the Sitecore Community and based on their contribution become an MVP.

If you are part of the Sitecore Community but not sure how to contribute or would like to have more visibility in the community you can sign up as a mentee and Sitecore will assign you a Sitecore MVP to mentor you.

If you are a Sitecore MVP and you would like to help other to contribute to the Community and be more visible, you can sign up to be a mentor and Sitecore will assign you a mentee.

To apply to the Sitecore MVP mentorship program as a mentor or mentee please send the Sitecore team an email at [mvp-program@sitecore.com](https://mailto:mvp-program@sitecore.com?subject=Mentor%20Program) with subject line "Mentor Program"

More information on the Sitecore MVP Program website: https://mvp.sitecore.com/Mentor-Program